# Front end undo/redo support?

Tags: front-end

I'm running Mathematica version 11 (for mac), and it seems like it only has one level of undo (which I believe was also the behaviour in version 9).  After undo, which didn't do anything close to undoing some magic keystroke that I made that killed a line and mangled another, I am left with no further undo option and no redo:

[image: busted undo redo]

However, I see on the wolfram community a claim that Mathematica 10 had an [implementation of multiple undo](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/290130).

Did this multiple undo get removed again in version 11, or is the claim that it was implemented not accurate?

Comment: On my Mac OS X, *Mathematica* 11.0.1, multiple undo works fine.

Comment: It certainly has multiple undo/redo, but it's crazy glitchy. Every time I desperately need it, it doesn't work; every time I delete a huge FE object and then hit undo just a few too many times--system's frozen for a good few seconds.

Answer (score 4):

This is not an answer. It is suggestion that needs a screen shot, so it can't be written as comment.

Have you checked the undo settings of your installation? You can do that in the Options Inspector.

[image: undo]

Also, note that multiple undo only works in input cells that have been evaluated.

Comment: My Undo options look like yours, but I don't seem to be able to change them.  The fact that "multiple undo only works in input cells that have been evaluated." appears to be what was seeing.  That is very counter-intuititive, and not at all like any other editor in the universe.

Comment: @PeeterJoot. "not at all like any other editor in the universe". Well, I wouldn't go that far.  If your experience has been with procedural language code editors, I can see where you coming from. However, many years ago, I wrote Lisp code with an editor that had much in common with the Mathematica code editor.

Comment: It's amazing the lengths people will go to defend the lack of functional UNDO in Mathematica. It's crazy.  @Peeter Joot, I feel your pain. I experience your pain. You are not imagining things. Indeed, the dirty secret is that Mathematica's broken undo was modeled on m_goldberg's Lisp editor from 1977, and hasn't been fixed or improved since.

Comment: I just banged my thumb with a hammer again -- accidentally deleted a phrase while editing -- no undo to recover it.  Again, I'm back in 1977 with @m_goldberg

Comment: @ChrisNadovich. I really don't understand why you are complaining to me. I can't do anything about it.  I have no connection to Wolfram. I urge you, instead, to complain to Wolfram tech support. The more complaints they get, the more likely something will be done to improve Mathematica's text editing.

Comment: I don't think I was complaining to you as much as just goofing at your suggestion that Mathematica's undo is modeled on what in 1977 some people thought was a good idea. Trust that I do indeed complain to them directly. Also trust that Wolfram tech support reads these SE posts.

Comment: For completeness, since this is the newest post I found regarding this, I had the same problem in Mathematica 13.2, and this was the correct solution.